# IOS: close viewcontroller and don't release it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting

In my project where I use ARC and storyboard I open a viewcontroller with this code:

```
SecondViewController *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondviewcontroller"];

    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and I close it with:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is there a way to not deallocate second and reopen it in its last status?

thansk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `second` a strong property in your class and check whether it's nil before deciding to instantiate it.